# How do i edit and replace one line of text with the file name

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, replace

How do i edit and replace one line of text for a html file with the file name don't care if i need to use a special software to be able to need to do this for about 1500 files
thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your code. Do you need to change the text line with a specific file name or to include an html file in that place? Do you have access to that html code?

Comment: <source src="z:\filename.mp4" type="video/webm">

Comment: This may be useful: notepad++ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Ctrl+Shift+F (Find in Files) has a replace option

Comment: i need to replace where is says filename witth the file itselfs name

Comment: is there a way to create a batch file that can input a variable from a list and then output that easily?